# Docker Build not reading files

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I have a docker image that I am trying to build for my Node JS API and I'm running into a crash every time I execute the docker file.

The Dockerfile and directory for my projects are as follows: [Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgxFx.png)

When I run `docker-compose up --build` at the project's terminal, I get this result: [Docker Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN2y2.jpg)

It tells me `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/app/api/products'` but as you can see, i have the 'products' folder in my directory.

I have used a docker build engine within VSCode to build a docker file for me, to just eventually researching and making my own. I have played around with root levels to make it work and calling specific files, but I'm having no luck. The app runs just fine with npm start. I am at a loss for what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker container's file system is case sensitive while yours is "Windows" which is case in-sensitive.

Problem you are having is due to your folder name being "Products" instead of "products" which you are trying to use.

[image]

Comment: wow. I am such a kumquat. Thank you.